# 10*($a0+4) with MIPS assembly instructions

Tags: mips, instructions

You guys are usually very quick and helpful when it comes to questions so I was going to ask for help regarding a MIPS problem that I am having. I gave it a try and you can see my code below, but I sense that it's wrong since the 10 is confusing me. All I need is for someone to tell me if I'm on the right track (if the code is wrong, I am new when it comes to MIPS), or maybe give hints/show a code that will work.

Here it is: `10*($a0+4)`, which shall me stored in `$v0`

My code:

```
addi $t0, $a0, 2
li $t1, $t1, 3
li $t2, $t2, 1
addi $t3, $t2, $t1
sll $v0, t3, $t0
```

Comment: please add comments to show what you understand. And did you try to assemble/run it?

Answer (score 0):

If you've put comments to the code you'll see problems right away

```
addi $t0, $a0, 2   # $t0 = $a0 + 2
li $t1, $t1, 3     # $t1 = 3
li $t2, $t2, 1     # $t2 = 1
addi $t3, $t2, $t1 # $t3 = $t2 + $t1 = 3
sll $v0, t3, $t0   # $v0 = $t3 << $t0 = 3 << ($a0 + 2) = 8*($a0 + 2)
```

But wait! `addi` is for adding immediates so those 2 lines would result in a syntax error. `li` is a pseudo instruction that takes a single operand, so the two `li` lines also has the wrong syntax. There's also a missing `$` in the last line for `t3`

To multiply x by 10 you can use `mult` instruction (probably not efficient in this case) or do `(x << 3) + (x << 1)`. One example implementation is like this

```
addi $a0, $a0, 4   # $a0 = $a0 + 4
sll  $a0, $a0, 1   # $a0 = $a0 << 1 = 2*$a0
sll  $t0, $a0, 2   # $t0 = $a0 << 3 = 8*$a0
add  $v0, $t0, $a0
```

Remember to write comments

Comment: Really appreciate the help!! I was very confused with this one.